# How to recurse back to start?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm a noob programmer, but I've been stuck on this one bit of code. How do you recurse back to start? I've tried several different methods but they all either take a ridiculous amount of code or don't work properly. I've been trying to implement this "simple" piece of code in all of my programming assignments, but it hasn't been working out. Thanks!

p.s. I've already finished the assignment. I'm just trying to make it more "complete".

```
public class OddProduct {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Inputs from user
       System.out.println("Enter an odd number");
       Scanner input_odd = new Scanner(System.in);
       int odd = input_odd.nextInt(); 

       int oddproduct = 1;

       //Multiplies all odd integers 
       for (int counter = 1; counter <= odd; counter = counter + 2){
            oddproduct = oddproduct * counter;
       }//end of for- loop 
       System.out.printf("\nThe product of all the odd integers up to %d is %d\n",
               odd, oddproduct);

       /* MY NOTES FOR RECURSE
       if (odd%2 == 1){ proceed normally} 
       else if (odd%2 != 1) { HOW TO LOOP BACK???}
       else { println = "Application closed"} 
       */
    }//end of main method

}//end of OddProduct class
```

Comment: As `recursion` is a specialized programming technique, I do not think you mean `recurse back to start` but rather `return` to start?  Anyway, probably what you want is a loop, that takes your input (and does logic) until a certain char is input?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yeah, I figured that I would need a while function, but I'm not sure what to put in it. I've literally spent hours on it. I would do other problems to destress. I just want to see how its done, like the counter method to stop loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your **Notes** I think this is what you require

```
   Scanner input_odd = new Scanner(System.in);
   int odd = 0; 

   while (odd % 2 != 1) {  // fails first time && if user enters even number
       System.out.println("Enter an odd number");
       odd = input_odd.nextInt(); 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. I did something very similar before, but I guess I have to be careful where to place it.

Comment: Yes, if you replace your first 4 lines of your main with this, it should work.  Also if this answer has been useful please consider to upvote and/or accept. Thanks